# Vue 3 Can I get a list of custom directives applied to the component?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Can I get a list of custom directives applied to a component?
In the instance returned by getCurrentInstance call, directives are null for current component. Expected 'highlight'
How can i get list of directives applied to current component? (Vue v3.1.2)

In Vue 2.x it was in this.$vnode.data.directives

https://jsfiddle.net/6e08styL/27/

html

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

js

```
const {
  createApp,
  getCurrentInstance
} = Vue

const app = createApp({
  template: `<test v-highlight="'red'"></test>`,
})

app.component('test', {
  name: 'test',
  template: `<div>{{msg}}</div>`,
  data: () => ({
      msg: 'Hello Vue.js'
  }),
  setup() {
      const instance = getCurrentInstance()
      console.log(instance)
  }
})

app.directive('highlight', {
  beforeMount(el, binding, vnode) {
      el.style.background = binding.value
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
```

console
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Y3h.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's available from:

```js
getCurrentInstance().vnode.dirs
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/madcfn1u/)